# Postmortem for a question about formal logic

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta

Recently the question, "[Computable Syntax](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/109887/48431)", hit the Hot Network Questions sidebar. It has an accepted answer and lots of good commentary.

Regardless, there's a couple glaring issues with the entire interaction, and I'd like to know if anybody has any postmortem insights that they'd like to share, so that we can do better as a community in the future. I recognize that this is somewhat open-ended, but I think that it's important to consider the quality of discourse. I don't know how to fix this, only how to point out what went wrong. In the question:

- The question asks several queries at once
- Terminology is confused: generic patterns like "computable" and "first-order logic" are treated as specific concretions
- Distractions are brought up, like "completeness theorem" and "Turing machine"
- Signs of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), as the questioner may be trying to formalize something they've discovered/invented
- Value judgements like "reasonably useful"

And in the comments and answers:

- Restating Wikipedia articles with slight changes
- Focusing on consistency over soundness
- Focusing on semantics over syntax
- Value judgements like "what makes a good formal system"
- Long meandering answers that do not directly answer the question as asked

I am not blaming anybody specifically. I merely think that this could have gone better. What do y'all think?

Comment: As the OP, I can admit that question wasn't properly understood. There is always a gap where I am (my knowledge), and where others are, which is why the question has come up. However, I received enough pointers where to look. Question undoubtedly has a very philosophical character, for it asks, loosely, "*what makes formal systems work*". It borders on exploring the relation between "principles" which make formal system work and the "intellect". Unfortunately, many responders gave technical answers -which are what they are - "just technically correct".

Comment: There are several answers that make good points. I'm surprised that the answer by Rodolfo was accepted: it is definitely weaker than many of the others and much of it misses the mark entirely.

Comment: @Ajax: That makes sense. It seems like a simple line of inquiry, but there's no formal bridge from the informal to the formal (or at least we haven't found one!) and [a barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchhausen_trilemma) preventing argumentation. I think many answers assumed that you were already on one side or the other.

Answer (score 1):

The subtopic that interests me the most are the “value judgments” and I’d like to collaborate with people on trying to propose some new moderation guidelines for that.